# Por que !! transforma uma expressão em boolean em javascript

Tags: javascript

Vi um exemplo uma vez que para transformar algo que não seja boolean em boolean em javascript basta usar o !! antes da expressão por exemplo  para valores "truthy" ou "falsy". Porém não entendi o por que, isso seria como dizer "não não"? Qual seria a diferença para só usar ! neste caso?

Comment: Se você tiver algo como `var foo = 1;` e fizer `console.log(!foo);` vai obter um valor booleano `false`, se fizer novamente `console.log(!!foo);`, então usar duas vezes o exclamação é como se estivesse fazendo `var foo = 1; foo = !foo; var foo = !foo; console.log(foo);`, ou seja, primeiro o interpretador faz uma operação com o primeiro ! a direita, e depois vem fazendo as operações do os esquerda (a partir da direita), você poderia fazer também `!!!foo;` e `!!!!foo;`, mas não teria sentido (mesmo que funcione), porque você só precisará para fazer uma vez cast para true ou false.

Comment: se o valor for *falsy*, um `!` vai transformar em `true`, se você tiver um valor `truthy` um ! vai transformar em `false`, então depende de como vai usar esse valor boolean. Agora se precisar que truthy seja exatamente como true (e não false) então vai ter que usar !!, o mesmo vale para falsy, se precisar que ele seja exatamente false.